# Register an user space call back function with USB driver

Tags: linux

How to register an user space call back function with USB driver for mass storage devices in Linux?
I got follwing messages on to console when usb stick is attached.

usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler G2
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0019E06B07F7A961877C02A9
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
scsi0 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler G2  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
SCSI device sda: 7818240 512-byte hdwr sectors (4003 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: assuming drive cache: write through
SCSI device sda: 7818240 512-byte hdwr sectors (4003 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: assuming drive cache: write through sda:sda1
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sda
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `udev` rule which executes a command when it is inserted. Basically you create a file containing a set of rules for matching, and the path to a program/script to run. It'll look something like this:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{serial}=="0019E06B07F7A961877C02A9", RUN+="/path/to/script arg1 arg2 ... argN"
```

This will run `/path/to/script` with the arguments `arg1` to `argN` when a device node named `sd?1` is created, where `?` is any character, with the serial number given in your data. You can get a lot of info from the `udevinfo` program to incorporate in the rule if you need better control over when it should fire. Such as if you want it to fire for all Kingston drives, for instance. Then you'd need to find the vendorID and maybe some more information unique to these drives.